# How to get JSX syntax highlighting working with monaco-editor and react?

Tags: javascript, jsx, monaco-editor

I am writing jsx code in monaco-editor,
and now the type checking is implemented,
but the syntax highlighting cannot be achieved

this is my configuration:

```
monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.setDiagnosticsOptions({
  noSemanticValidation: false,
  noSyntaxValidation: false,
})

monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.setCompilerOptions({
  target: monaco.languages.typescript.ScriptTarget.Latest,
  allowNonTsExtensions: true,
  moduleResolution: monaco.languages.typescript.ModuleResolutionKind.NodeJs,
  module: monaco.languages.typescript.ModuleKind.CommonJS,
  noEmit: true,
  esModuleInterop: true,
  jsx: monaco.languages.typescript.JsxEmit.React,
  reactNamespace: "React",
  jsxFactory: 'React.createElement',
  allowJs: true,
  typeRoots: ["node_modules/@types"],
})
```

and react typings check:

```
monaco?.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib(
        typings, 
        `file:///node_modules/@types/react.d.ts.d.ts`
)
```

Here's an example:

[image: There are code hints but no highlighting]